# Parser Element with child element

Tags: parsing, swift

i have for example this document:

```
<Category>
 <Name>NameParent</Name>
  <Category>
   <Category>
    <Name>NameChild1</Name>
     <Category>
      <Name>NameChild2</Name>
     </Category>
    </Category>
   </Category>
</Category>
```

and this is my class:

```
class Category: NSObject {
    var attributeID:NSString = ""
    var nameCategory:NSString = "nameNotFound"
    var objCategory:Category?
}
```

how to see category is a recursive class.

the children may have, in turn, other children, and have an unlimited number how can I handle this?
how can I structure this in the parser?

EDIT: at this time, the parser can not find the father and their children, but I can not save them well in the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this with some kind of stack. On each open `<Category>` push a new element on the stack and on each `</Category>` pop the last one from the stack.

One simple approach is to use an array for the stack.

Create a class for the category elements. While parsing, whenever `didStartElement` fires with `elementName == "Category"` create a new instance of that class and do the further processing until `didEndElement` fires, again with `elementName == "Category"`

Comment: Exactly, this is what I want to do.

I am a Java programmer and unfortunately I can not implement it in swift.

Here I have loaded a piece of code: http://piratepad.net/stacl

As you can see I can not, once you find the child, to implement the ogetto properly.

Comment: I just updated my answer with some thoughts on how to implement this.