# Recursive element of NSXMLParser in ObjectiveC and Swift

Tags: ios, recursion, swift, nsxmlparser

i have a document XML with a recursive element, like this :

```
    <Category id="IND">
     <Name>father</Name>
      <Category id="IND_TURN_ORD">
       <Name>child1</Name>
        <Category id="IND_TURN_ORD">
         <Name> child of the child </Name>
        </Category>
      </Category>
    </Category>
```

**How do I create a recursive parser for this document?**

This is my code i have try :

*When i found elementName == "Category"*

```
     func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        if (elementName == "Category") && (!categoryIsOpen){
            println(“found child“)
            currentChildOpen++
            categoryIsOpen = true

            Category.listCategory[countCategory].append(Category())
            // Call recursive func


            }
}
```

Now I should call the recursive function, to make a loop and see if it has categoy children. 
But I do not know what to switch to, and how do ogetto cycle.

Some Suggested? thanks

EDIT:

*this is my class Category:*

```
class Category: NSObject {
    var attributeID:NSString = ""
    var nameCategory:NSString = "nameNotFound"
    var hasChild = false
    var isOpen = false
    var level = 0
    //var children:[Category] = []
    var children = [Category]()
}
```

I accept advice in swift and objective-C

Thanks

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588119/nsxmlparser-accessing-string-values-error/26589108#26589108) to get a start on this.

Comment: not really. Your XML document is true that children with the same name element, but the attribute changes. So in your case just check the attribute name. 

What I want to do it should not be difficult, it would be enough to have the name of the next item, but I can not.

Comment: For recursive XML elements, I have posted an [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339273/parser-element-with-child-element/26339724#26339724)

Comment: OK, but that will not keep the tree structure, and when I view the data is all mixed up.

Comment: There is no one-liner to parse recursive XML documents, you have to implement that in a way that meets your needs.

Comment: You can not just know the name of the neighbor? I saw there is a chance to get to know the former, but the next I can not.

Comment: XML documents are parsed top-down. You have to take care on processing the elements. Complex document structures require complex parsing strategies. See my answer I mentioned above and think about building a stack array for traversing through the elements. Sorry, you cannot expect that someone here simply posts a block of code which is exactly what you need for your document structure. I can only give you some hints to get you started.